# Merge two dictionaries and if duplicate keys found , add their values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I have 2 python dictionaries:

```
x =  {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}  
y =  {'bookB': 1, 'bookD': 2, 'bookF': 3, 'bookL': 4, 'bookX': 5}
```

I want to  merge the above two dictionaries and create an another dictionary. 
I tried this code:

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

But the key values are overriding in this case. I want a dictionary in which if there are duplicates , add their values or some other action can also be there like subtraction, multiplication etc. So my motto is not to override the duplicate values but to perform some action if got any duplicate. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
Convert `x` and `y` to `collections.Counter` objects and just sum them (`Counter` supports `__add__`ition.)

```
from collections import Counter

z = dict(Counter(x) + Counter(y))
z 
{'bookA': 1,
 'bookB': 3,
 'bookC': 3,
 'bookD': 6,
 'bookE': 5,
 'bookF': 3,
 'bookL': 4,
 'bookX': 5}
```

---

**Option 2**
You can write a neat little dict comprehension using `dict.pop` -

```
z = {k : x[k] + y.pop(k, 0) for k in x}
```

Now, update `z` with what's left in `y` -

```
z.update(y)
```

Or,

```
z = {**z, **y} # python3.6
```

```
z
{'bookA': 1,
 'bookB': 3,
 'bookC': 3,
 'bookD': 6,
 'bookE': 5,
 'bookF': 3,
 'bookL': 4,
 'bookX': 5}
```

Comment: What does this line means  z = {**z, **y} ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla It's python3.6 syntax for combining two dicts.

Comment: I know, but there is no 'x' in it , how it will  take elements of x ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla Because `z` already contains the contents of `x`. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Ok got it. It is not a single statement. It also includes this line: z = {k : x[k] + y.pop(k, 0) for k in x} . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

cs95's solutions are nice, but for the sake of options, here's a 1-liner comprehension:

```
x.update({k:(v + x[k]) if k in x else v for k,v in y.items()})
```

That modifies your `x` dict in-place; if you can't do that then copy it to `z` first:

```
z = x.copy()
z.update({k:(v + z[k]) if k in z else v for k,v in y.items()})
```